# Excel - steepest and least steep lines

Tags: excel, math, graph, physics

Is there any way in Excel that I can get the steepest line and least steep line, given a linear graph?

If it's not possible to get these lines, is there a way I can (using Excel) calculate the gradient given a line.

Below, the graph I am working with.

[image]

Comment: In the above example your slope is 0.8919.  That is a description of how steep the line is.  If another line has a slope greater than that it can be said it is "steeper."  If this isn't what you're looking for add what you have tried or give a better description of the data you are working with.

Comment: I think he's looking for the line with the highest slope, which starts at (X1, Y1min) and then passes through all error boxes (near upper edge without going outside the box). And inversely for the lowest slope (X1, Y1max), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to write a VBA macro to do this. This functionality is not built in.

Note that in some cases, there is no solution to this problem.  In your example, if the last point is at (100,0) instead of (100,81), then no line exists that can traverse all error boxes.

Comment: For this kind of problem, I would suggest to look at more advanced tools like Matlab, which might offer this capability.